# Find item(s) in a nested dictionary by secondary key

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

This is my problem: I have a nested dictionary (primary keys: orderIds, secondary keys: productIds).

My scheme:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Task>>>
```

I need to look for the `productId` and return that value (`Task` object).

It's usually not the case that a product key appears in several orders. So it's unique.

Here is a json example:

```json
{
  "O1": {
    "P1": [
      {
        "Field": "V1"
      },
      {
        "Field": "V7"
      }
    ],
    "P2": [
      {
        "Field": "V2"
      },
      {
        "Field": "V8"
      }
    ]
  },
  "O2": {
    "P1": [
      {
        "Field": "V3"
      },
      {
        "Field": "V5"
      }
    ],
    "P2": [
      {
        "Field": "V4"
      },
      {
        "Field": "V6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I look for productId "P5" I want to get...

```json
[{"Field":"V5"}]
```

The only way I found that runs is...

```
return base.Values.Single(x => x.ContainsKey(productId))[productId];
```

*//**base** is the nested Dictionary*

But I don't like what I'm doing here. Because I detach the correct dictionary from the collection (values) where the key exists and finally I fetch only the value via key filtering (collection[key]).

That are basically two steps, but I suspect there is an easier way with just one step. - I just can't find this one.

Maybe you can help me out. :)

Comment: So it works, but you want to know if there's a better way? I think this is a code review.

Comment: Yeah and nay. It's a part of a process simulation.

I have thousands of orders a day with 1-5 products each. (We design gaming PCs and screw them together as desired.) The simulation should run as quickly as possible and since we sometimes have very complex or large orders (e.g. for game cons), the production line also stretches.

Therefore, at the end of the retrieval, a full simulation (all calculations) may only take a few milliseconds. So I try to avoid any slowing down of the code. Therefore I am looking for the optimal way.

Answer (score 1):

For performance tuning, use HashSet instead of List.
I also can recommend ISBN: 0321637003 (LINQ to Objects), maybe there is an updated version. But anyway its still very good content.
If you have millions of entries in your dict, you can try PLINQ.

> return base.Values.Single(x => x.ContainsKey(productId))[productId];

The Sample json throws an exception, because your productId (P1, P2) is not unique and P5 does not exist.

> If I look for productId "P5" I want to get...
> [{"Field":"V5"}]
> There Is no P5

I am not sure its helping but, here is my sample code. I have put your json into a file and deserialize it.

```
var lFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\_test\data.json");
using var lReader = lFile.OpenText();
var lJsonStr = lReader.ReadToEnd();
var lDicDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<ProductId>>>>(lJsonStr);

//var lTest1 = lDicDic.Values.Single(x => x.ContainsKey("P1"))["P1"]; //Not working, P1 is not unique!
var lTest2 = lDicDic["O2"]["P1"];
//contains  => "Field": "V3" + "Field": "V5"

var lTest3 = lDicDic
   .SelectMany(p => p.Value.Values.SelectMany(qItem => qItem))
   .FirstOrDefault(qProducts => qProducts.Field == "V5");
//contains  => "Field": "V5"

var lTest4 = lDicDic["O2"]["P1"].Last();
//contains  => "Field": "V5"
```

EDIT:

After your Fiddler code I was able to test it.

```
public List<MyTask> GetByProductId(string productId)
{
    var lProductDict = Tasks.Values.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContainsKey(productId));
    return lProductDict?.GetValueOrDefault(productId);
}
```

My stomach tells my, your current approach is hard to make any better ;)
If you have a lot of calls on this nasted dict, and its changing not very often it could make sense to refactor the dict from TopDown to BottomUp at the beginning for the processing.

Anyway, If my comments are helpful plz upvote my answere :)

If I were you I would make some testcases with real data.
Dont forget: If you are in DEBUG mode, to enable "Optimize Code" at the Project. In my testcase, I had an AVG of 47ms without and 42ms with optimized code:
[image]

You can give PLINQ a try:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq

Here us my test scenario:

```
var lStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
lStopWatch.Restart();
var lJobs = new Jobs("F1");
const int TestOrderCount = 1000000;
const int TestAvgCount = 1000;
for (var lIndex = 1; lIndex < TestOrderCount; lIndex++)
{
    var lNoStr = lIndex.ToString("D6");
    lJobs.Add($"O{lNoStr}", $"P{lNoStr}", $"V{lNoStr}");
}

var GetTimes = new List<long>();
var lRandom = new Random();
var lTestCases = Enumerable
    .Range(1, TestAvgCount - 1)
    .Select(r => $"P{lRandom.Next(1, TestOrderCount - 1):D6}")
    .ToList();

var lSetupTimeMs = lStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Debug.WriteLine($"SetupTimeMs: {lSetupTimeMs}");
foreach (var lTestCase in lTestCases)
{
    lStopWatch.Restart();
    var lTest = lJobs.GetByProductId(lTestCase);
    GetTimes.Add(lStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

var lAvg = GetTimes.Sum() / TestAvgCount; //AVG Ms per get
Debug.WriteLine($"AVG: {lAvg}");
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wasn't paying attention to **non-existent keys**. So I need to use `.SingleOrDefault()` and `.productDict.GetValueOrDefault()`. » Here my sample: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/swynkT) in Line #54 the method **GetByProductId()**. _//this is just a simple example, not the whole amount of all my classes_

Comment: Okay, this is nice. I tried to use IEnumerable, but missed the Linq methods then. So I switched to Dicts and Lists. But the HashSet is maybe a good idea. And PLINQ is very hard to read, I think, but maybe the quicker way. - I'll read about and try to improve my skills for that.